# Show some value from data in Laravel's Blade

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm useing Laravel's Blade to show data `{{$value->blanko}}` and the result is **CA123456789**.

how to show only **CA** from the data in the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [str_limit](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers),

Eg:

```
{{ Str::limit($value->blanko, 2) }}
```

Comment: it works, but there's '...' in the end like CA.. how to not show the triple dot '...'

Comment: Class 'Str' not found

Comment: use Illuminate\Support\Str;  - put this in your controller @www.cahyonegoro.com

Comment: still not found 'Str'

Comment: found it, use string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )

Answer (score 1):

Please use function like as example `$result = substr($myStr, 0, 2);` in controller or use laravel function `str_limit`